# Проблема подключения базы данных PostgreSQL к проекту в vs Code

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Помогите пожалуйста!!!
Проблема подключения базы данных PostgreSQL к проекту в vs Code.

Мой код для подключения к бд:

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const { threadId } = require('worker_threads');
const app = express();

const { Pool } = require('pg');

const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'SchoolProject',
  password: '123',
  port: 5432,
});

// Проверка подключения к базе данных
pool.connect((err, client, release) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error('Ошибка подключения к базе данных', err.stack);
    }
    console.log('Успешное подключение к базе данных PostgreSQL');
    client.release();
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log(`Сервер запущен на порту ${PORT}`);
});
```

Когда пишу в консоль node index.js, в терминале выводиться следующее

Ошибка подключения к базе данных error: ���� ������ "SchoolProject" �� ����������

- at Parser.parseErrorMessage
  (C:\Users\79137\Desktop\Всё\Прога\Kurs\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:287:98

)

- at Parser.handlePacket
  (C:\Users\79137\Desktop\Всё\Прога\Kurs\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:126:29)
- at Parser.parse
  (C:\Users\79137\Desktop\Всё\Прога\Kurs\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:39:38)
- at Socket.
  (C:\Users\79137\Desktop\Всё\Прога\Kurs\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:11:42)
- at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
- at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:376:12)
- at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:349:9)
- at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:286:10)
- at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)

В pgAdmin указал всё также:  user: 'postgres',
host: 'localhost',
database: 'SchoolProject',
password: '123',
port: 5432,

Я новичок, подскажите пожалуйста.

P.S.
полный текст ошибки
Сервер запущен на порту 3000
error: ���� ������ "SchoolProject" �� ����������

- at Parser.parseErrorMessage
  (C:\Users\79137\Desktop\Всё\Прога\Kurs\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:287:98)
- at Parser.handlePacket
  (C:\Users\79137\Desktop\Всё\Прога\Kurs\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:126:29)
- at Parser.parse
  (C:\Users\79137\Desktop\Всё\Прога\Kurs\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:39:38)
- at Socket.
  (C:\Users\79137\Desktop\Всё\Прога\Kurs\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:11:42)
- at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
- at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:376:12)
- at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:349:9)
- at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:286:10)
- at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
- length: 101,
- everity: '�����',
- code: '3D000',
- detail: undefined,
- hint: undefined,
- position: undefined,
- internalPosition: undefined,
- internalQuery: undefined,
- where: undefined,
- schema: undefined,
- table: undefined,
- column: undefined,
- dataType: undefined,
- constraint: undefined,
- file: 'postinit.c',
- line: '1021',
- routine: 'InitPostgres'
  }
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не плохо было бы это расшифровать "�". Проверьте кодировку файлов, что бы ромбики ушли. Так же покажите полный текст ошибки `console.error(err)`

Comment: Здравствуйте. Добавил полный текст ошибки к вопросу. Подскажите, как изменить кодировку файлов. Спасибо

Comment: У вас ошибка с кодом `code: '3D000'` и текстом: База данных SchoolProject не существует. Проверяйте название

Comment: Я добавил скрин с pgAdmin. Вроде всё правильно указываю

Comment: на картинке у вас некий-внутри-pgAdminский-сервер названный "SchoolProject" и в нём база данных "postgres". короче, нету у вас базы данных "SchoolProject"

Comment: ...Мда. 
Помогло.
Спасибо вам всем большое!!))

Comment: И позабодтесь о кодировке получаемых сообщений об ошибке. Погуглите, как что и где поправить. Либо кодировка файлов у вас не та, либо ответ от БД идет не в той кодировке

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое